# VBA Adding columns to MS Word table with mixed widths

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to make a script to add a column on the left hand side of a MS Word table.
The tables are already in existing documents with mixed widths, so the `Me.Tables.Item(1).Columns.Add(BeforeColumn:=Me.Tables.Item(1).Columns(1))` method will not work.
I did see while doing my research that I may have to insert it from a cell selection.(Like most thing I lost the reference to the page and couldn't find again)
Could anyone point me to a good resource for this or help me out in any way?

Comment: I resolved this with 'Selection.InsertColumns'

Answer (score 0):

I got around this by selecting a cell and using

```
Selection.InsertColumns
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this syntax:

```
Dim mDoc As Document
Set mDoc = ActiveDocument
Dim Tbl1 As Table
Set Tbl1 = mDoc.Tables(1)

Tbl1.Columns.Add BeforeColumn:=Tbl1.Columns(1)
```

Comment: Why would in removing the parentheses from (BeforeColumn:=Me.Tables.Item(1).Columns(1)).  Make any difference?

Comment: @RichardH I can't aswer your question (I'm a self-taught). It should not, but sometimes it doesn't work.